# ansible module to comment multiple lines in a file

Tags: ansible

I need to comment multiple lines in a text file, Is it possible to achieve using `lineinfile` module

Text File

```
line
line2
line3
---
---
line y
line vv
--
--
```

Now in need to comment line y and line vv. how this can be done using `lineinfile` or `replace` module ?

Comment: Maybe you can provide a minimal reproducible example of your text file and describe your use case in more detail and show what you are trying to do actually. One could come up with already existing good solutions then.

Comment: With respect to [mre] avoid 'real world examples' unless they are **minimal**.

Comment: @VladimirBotka, OK, going to do ...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: The module *replace* seems to fit better to your use case.

Details: Given the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.txt 
line
line2
line3
---
---
line y
line vv
--
--
```

Declare the variables with the comment mark and the list of the lines you want to comment

```yaml
    cmnt: '#'
    cmnt_lines:
      - line y
      - line vv
```

Because all lines in the list *cmnt_lines* are uniquely present in the file both [*lineinfile*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#ansible-builtin-lineinfile-module-manage-lines-in-text-files)

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/test.txt
        regexp: '^\s*{{ cmnt }}*\s*{{ item }}$'
        line: '{{ cmnt }} {{ item }}'
      loop: "{{ cmnt_lines }}"
```

and [*replace*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#ansible-builtin-replace-module-replace-all-instances-of-a-particular-string-in-a-file-using-a-back-referenced-regular-expression) will give the same result

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: /tmp/test.txt
        regexp: '^\s*{{ cmnt }}*\s*{{ item }}$'
        replace: '{{ cmnt }} {{ item }}'
      loop: "{{ cmnt_lines }}"
```

The differences between *lineinfile* and *replace*:

- The module *replace* will replace all matching lines while *lineinfile* will replace only the last one.
- In the mofule *lineinfile*, if the regular expression is not matched, the line will be added to the file.

---

Notes:

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    cmnt: '#'
    cmnt_lines:
      - line y
      - line vv

  tasks:

    - replace:
        path: /tmp/test.txt
        regexp: '^\s*{{ cmnt }}*\s*{{ item }}$'
        replace: '{{ cmnt }} {{ item }}'
      loop: "{{ cmnt_lines }}"
```

- Both options are idempotent. Quoting from *lineinfile* [*regexp*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-regexp):

> When modifying a line the regexp should typically match both the initial state of the line as well as its state after replacement by line to ensure idempotence.

- Explanation of the Python regexp:

```
^ .................... matches beginning of string
\s*{{ cmnt }}*\s* .... any combination of whitespaces and the value of cmnt
{{ item }} ........... content of the line without comment
$ .................... matches end of string
```

- To uncomment the line change the parameter *line* or *replace*

```yaml
        replace: '{{ item }}'
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given text file, a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Comment out lines
    lineinfile:
      path: file.txt
      regexp: '^line {{ item }}'
      line: '# line {{ item }}'
    loop: # with values
      - y
      - vv
```

will comment out and result into the requested output.

**Dry-Run with `--diff`**

```bash
TASK [Comment out lines] *********
--- before: file.txt (content)
+++ after: file.txt (content)
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@
 line3
 ---
 ---
-line y
+# line y
 line vv
 --
 --

changed: [localhost] => (item=y)
--- before: file.txt (content)
+++ after: file.txt (content)
@@ -4,6 +4,6 @@
 ---
 ---
 # line y
-line vv
+# line vv
 --
 --

changed: [localhost] => (item=vv)
```

**Result**

```yaml
TASK [Comment out lines] ***
ok: [localhost] => (item=y)
ok: [localhost] => (item=vv)
```

```
~/test$ cat file.txt
line
line2
line3
---
---
# line y
# line vv
--
--
```

**Further Documentation**

and some more examples.

- [`lineinfile` module – Manage lines in text files - Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#examples)

Comment: Thanks @U880D I will try this suggestion, My concern is if my text file contains repeated lines ( For Ex line3 is repeated) then i wish to replace only a particular line3 instead all line3. IS this possible to achieve ?

Comment: As mentioned in the [other solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75541572/6771046), "_lineinfile will replace only the last one_" found. If the last line found means not "a particular" you'll probably need to edit your initial question an provide more details regarding the use case.

Comment: @Sam; now is the time for the real-world example to show why you *`"wish to replace only a particular line3 instead all line3"`*. [edit] the question and make it **minimal**.